# The app just crashes whenever I go into the activity

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming

The code is

```
public class TwelfthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Object HlsMediaSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twelfth);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory();
    HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
            new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("http://37.77.2.234:1935/beyaz/live/chunklist_w269671748.m3u8"));
    SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    player.setMediaSource((MediaSource) HlsMediaSource);
    player.prepare();
}
```

}

No errors pop up anywhere but the app itself just crashes

Comment: Don't tell me it is because of `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: Provide the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private SimpleExoPlayer moviePlayer;
private PlayerView playerView;
private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
private int currentWindow = 0;
private long playbackPosition = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twelfth);

    playerView = findViewById(R.id.moviePlayer);

    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(this, new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory());  
    trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd());
    DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder().setBufferDurationsMs(50000, 50000, 4000, 1024).build();
    moviePlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, new DefaultRenderersFactory(this)).setLoadControl(loadControl).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build();
    playerView.setPlayer(moviePlayer);
    
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(getString(R.string.app_name));
    MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).setAllowChunklessPreparation(true).createMediaSource(new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(Uri.parse("http://37.77.2.234:1935/beyaz/live/chunklist_w269671748.m3u8")).build());

    moviePlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
    moviePlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    moviePlayer.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
    moviePlayer.prepare();

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for the code. The only error now comes from the currentWindow and playbackPosition. Do you have any idea how to fix these? It says they cannot resolve the symbols

Comment: Check the edited answer and If it answered your question mark it as answered.

Comment: Yes the program is working now. I was wondering if you knew why there is no option to maximise the screen? Is this done a limitation of ExoPlayer or is there code I need to write?

Comment: Ask a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show AndroidManifest file and how you open this activity?

Also, please try to add https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/SimpleExoPlayer.html#addListener(com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.EventListener) and see maybe there is an error.

And maybe restart android studio if there is no info in logcat about the crash